# How to measure explained variance in y in the case of regression dilution bias?

Tags: regression, r-squared

I would like to find the explained variance in `y` by `x` when both `y` and `x` has measurement errors which lead to having [regression dilution bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_dilution) for an OLS fit. I handle finding the correct fit which explains the functional relationship between these two variables by using [ranged major axis regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmodel2/lmodel2.pdf) (RMA) instead of the regular linear regression, but then the `R^2` drops significantly since RMA, unlike OLS, does not fit the model by just optimizing the `|y_predicted-y|` .

I am wondering what is the best way of measuring the explained variance in `y` by `x` in this case?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data, or add the data to your question?